# Why is the = operator deleted, and how can I work around it?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set one of the elements of an array to be a different object. But, the compiler is deleting the `=` operator. Why is it doing that here, exactly? And how can I work around it?

Example code:

```
struct IntContainer
{

    IntContainer(const int value) :
    value(value)
    {
    }

    IntContainer() :
    IntContainer(0)
    {
    }

    const int value;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    IntContainer intContainers[3];
    IntContainer newIntContainer(420);
    intContainers[0] = newIntContainer; // <-- Causes compiler error

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error I'm getting when compiling this snippet is:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:23:24: error: use of deleted function 'IntContainer& IntContainer::operator=(const IntContainer&)'
     intContainers[0] = newIntContainer; // <-- Causes compiler error:
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:8: note: 'IntContainer& IntContainer::operator=(const IntContainer&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct IntContainer
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:8: error: non-static const member 'const int IntContainer::value', can't use default assignment operator
```

Comment: How would you assign something to a `const` variable?

Comment: @NathanOliver cast it away :D

Comment: Isn't it assigning to the value in the constructor(s) here?

Comment: @UKMonkey I know your joking but... *shudder*

Comment: @gromit190 - Not assigning, initializing.

Comment: @gromit190 No.  In the constructor you initialize it.  You are allowed to do that.  You can never assign to a `const` variable.

Comment: The compiler can't provide a default assignment operator or copy constructor because of the const member. You'll need to provide your own.

Comment: @UKMonkey - Even in jest, I wouldn't say this in such a public space. Already I feel a disturbance in the force. Like millions of programmers raging as their code breaks at the same time.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're right, the follow up question of 'I tried this and now it crashes at run time' would be completely self inflicted

Comment: Do not use `const` or reference members. On top of the "assignment" issue, they're also an easy source of undefined behavior when objects are commonly constructed and destructed on the same storage (ex: `std::vector<IntContainer>`). It's complicated to explain in a comment, but you most certainly don't want to risk subtle UB every time you store your object in a container

Comment: `non-static const member 'const int IntContainer::value', can't use default assignment operator` seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Why do you want to "work around it"? Why not *understand* what's going on and matching your design to your requirements?

Comment: @KABoissonneault - *"It's complicated to explain in a comment"* then write an answer. You can tie it with why the standard deletes the assignment operator.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry, bad choice of words by me. I'd rather understand it and improve my design, like you say

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler generally gives you `operator=` and the copy constructor for free, but when a class contains a `const` member, it makes no sense to generate `operator=` because you can't perform an assignment to the `const` member.

You could write your own, but you still wouldn't be able to assign values to the `const` member.

Comment: So my only option is to remove the const member? (Use a class instead, make the member private?)

Comment: @gromit190 Removing the `const` member will solve this issue, yes. However, the actual solution to the problem depends on the purpose of that class. Maybe it turns out that the right decision is to keep the member `const`, and simply never make assignments! If your purpose is to just stop direct access to the member, then I suppose using a class and making the member private is correct. Again, the solution to the problem depends on what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you need `const` semantics to preserve the invariants of your object, then encapsulation is definitely a valid solution

Comment: I see. In my case it seems making it a class with a private member is the more reasonable option. Thanks!